# When jQuery's $(".foo li") returns an object as a result, what exact is the type of object called?

Tags: jquery

Let's say if we initialize some selected result:

```
init : function() {
    this.searchButton = $("#searchButton");
    this.listItems = $("#product-list li");
}
```

I wonder what is the official name is for the object returned by `$("#product-list li")`?  I sometimes called it jQuery selector object or selector, but it is somewhat vague.  Selector can just be the string `"#product-list li"`, and jQuery selector object may be better, except the results and length that indicates the number of matches is all inside the object, so it is not just a selector object because the results are inside.  Is there a formal name for this object?  For example, if I commit the above code using svn or git, should the comment really be "initializing jQuery selector objects"?

Comment: It's a [jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery), which hold a list of DOM elements.

Comment: When you call the `$()` function and pass a selector to it, you create a new `jQuery object`. Of course, in JavaScript, functions are objects too, so that means that `$` (and `jQuery`, of course) has properties and methods, too. Hence, the formal name for this object is **jQuery object**

Comment: It's really just a wrapper around a collection of Dom elements. It doesn't have to be a "selector" per se. For example `$(document.body)` or `$("<div>")` both return a jQuery object, but neither is a sector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The colloquial name for it is a 'jQuery object', although as far as javascript is concerned, if you do a `typeof` against it it's just a plain old `object`.

Comment: +1. Official API docs call it "jQuery object instances". http://api.jquery.com/category/properties/jquery-object-instance-properties/

Comment: Furthermore, `$('#searchButton')` is also a "jQuery object", as are all objects returned by the `$` function.

Comment: [`typeof`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) never gets more specific than "`object`", so that particular observation is not very useful. A more meaningful inspection of the "type" of a jQuery object would be to look at the result of `Object.getPrototypeOf($()))`.